# Facing 403 Forbidden Error in Nuxt3: DevProxy Configuration Not Redirecting Axios Calls as Expected

Tags: proxy, nuxt3

I tried config devProxy in Nuxt3, but it is not working.

my project spec

- "nuxt": "^3.4.2",
- "axios": "^1.4.0",

This is my api call code

```
const signupWithDB =  async () => {
  const response = await axios.post('/user/signup', {
    "userId": "string",
    "userPassword": "0000"
  });
  console.log(response);
}
```

I want baseUrl changed by proxy.
This is my nuxt3 config.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        devProxy: {
            '/user/signup': {
                target: '**MY_TARGET_URL**',
                changeOrigin: true,
                prependPath: true,
            }
        }
    },
});
```

It was not working. I did face to "403 forbidden ERROR".
I think the devProxy is not working..
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V9xB.png)

I was expecting..

api request 'http://localhost:3000/user/signup' to '**MY_TARGET_URL**/user/signup'

NO MORE ERROR !!